# Mozilla Firefox browser POST and PUT requests not work (MEAN project)

Tags: node.js, angular

In my MEAN-stack project I found some issues when tested it in Mozilla Firefox browser. The problem is when I send PUT or POST requests it doesn't work (but GET works well). 
This is headers (node.js):

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    express.static('public');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-type');
    res.setHeader("Allow-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});
```

This is baseServiceController's put function:

```
public Put<T>(url: string, data): Observable<T> {
    this.observer.next(true);
    return this.http.put(url, data).pipe(map((result: T) => {
        return result as T;
    }), catchError(this.handleError), finalize(() => {
        this.observer.next(false);
    }));
}
```

This is the service's put request:

```
public vote = (id: string, data: VoteModel): Observable<VoteModel> => {
    return this.Put<VoteModel>(`${utilities.baseUrl}/vote/${id}`, data);
}
```

When I send the request immediately works catch block and calls handleError function. In Chrome, Edge, Opera everything works well. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: As every problem involving an error: by starting to read the error.

Comment: There is no error, the request not even go. When I click the button to send the request it calls handleError function, but in console there is no error, and network also empty.

Comment: There is an error, otherwise the handleError function, by catchError(), wouldn't be called. Inspect that error.

Comment: There is only "Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/vote/5dde32ee57c69e31e433bb0a: 0 Unknown Error" message that comes from back-end, but in console and network it isn't shown

Comment: It doesn't come from the backend. And it's certainly caused by a CORS problem. Do you see the pre-flight request (OPTIONS) being sent?

Comment: No the OPTIONS also isn't sent. And what to add or remove in request headers to solve this?

Comment: Seems I find the reason of the problem. It is caused because I run the localhost  in https and the browser finds in it danger and blocks the requests. when I run it in http everything works well.